# Setting mock location from Cordova Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-gps

Is there any way to set the mock location coordinates from Cordova?
Perhaps there is a plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

I developed an app that I needed a Mock Location, and I do a lot of my testing using Localhost in IIS before testing on a device or emulator.

1. Global Variable _testLocalHost = true
2. I have a function called isRunningLocalHost() and I check that anytime if I need Mock Data. I have use a similar technique when testing on published apps.

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to mock the location. But to control a mock location provider from the app